# What are the best versions to react now?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm new in React and NPM. I'm studying React/React-router and practicing it, but that React just give me errors and more errors. My question here is: which versions to react and their dependencies are suitable/stable for now, 2017 year, I don't know if that question is on the suitable place, but thanks for the attention.

Below are my React dependencies versions

```
package.json
{
  "name": "first",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^3.3.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^3.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "webpack": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack" //I would change that after
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5"
  }
}
```

The repository is here: [Repository](https://github.com/thecodermarcelo/debian-react-first), that repo is using **react-router**

Some errors that occur:

```
Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

What errors are you getting?

Couple of things:

instead of using `babel-preset-2015` try using `babel-preset-env` (im pretty sure they are transitioning to just using env.)

Also you need to add babel-core to dev dependencies `yarn add -D babel-core`.

But you would need to post the errors in order for someone to really pinpoint where you are going wrong.

Cheers

Comment: A lot of errors, but they all are bonded with `react-router`

Comment: could you post them? usually if you are building just a web app you probably wouldn't need react-router and react-router-dom you could just use react-router-dom(which is for the web)